# Deploying AD FS web application to multiple environments

Tags: asp.net, deployment, adfs

Background:

I have an ASP.NET web app configured for federation with AD FS. I'm using VS 2012, and have TFS for source control, builds and deployments.

We're currently deploying by copying the built files from the build server (TFS) to the alpha environment. From there we would copy from alpha to beta, then from beta to production. So there is not a unique build for each environment. The way we're handling environment-specific settings right now is there is one config file that has all the settings for each environment Let's call this EnvironmentSpecificSettings.config (I'll refer to it below). There is a static file on each server that indicates which environment the server should be in, and so when that config file is read in, the matching settings can be applied.

The problem:

The ADFS configuration is handled in the web.config. There are a few things that are specific to the environment. How might I handle this within my current deployment paradigm? I had a couple of ideas:

1. include a file reference in the web.config that reads in a static environment-specific file that would not be part of the deployment.
2. Try to pull something off in Application_Start that would read in settings from EnvironmentSpecificSettings.config (mentioned above) and alter the web.config.
3. Try to tweak the configuration of the WSFederationAuthenticationModule at runtime

the first idea (#1) is less than optimal because it requires files hanging around outside of source control and outside of deployments, however it should work easily enough. Next, #2 I kinda think isn't possible. I'm not sure you can change your web.config like I am hoping, but maybe? Finally, #3 Is only reasonable because I'm in a special situation where I'm not doing regular passive authentication, instead I'm manually redirecting to adfs, so I have a chance to change settings, such as injecting the whr parameter to avoid HRD. So, it might be possible, however, I'm not sure how or if you can change some of these values on the fly such as thumbprint, or wsFederation issuer or realm.

Does anyone have any better ideas or experience in handling environment-specific settings without doing the visual studio web deploys with transforms?

Comment: I don't get it. Can't you deploy different web.configs for each of your environments?

Comment: Just have all of them in source, e.g. Web.alpha.config, Web.beta.config, and then have the copy process only copy the correct one? I guess. Maybe my EnvironmentSettings should be that way too rather than all in one file? I dunno, I have really limited experience. Is that how people generally go about it? I guess one drawback is that then when you want to make a change that applies to all environments, you have to change several files instead of one...

Comment: Rather than having multiple configs I suggest as follows. Have an xml file with your config parameters. Have your configs built with masks. Have a simple tool that rewrites config files by replacing masks with values from xml file. After you deploy, run the tool that updates the config. By having multiple xmls in different servers, you can quickly deploy, rewrite and have correct configs in different environments.